# Should I refer to the following as a "handrail," "guard rail," or a "wooden handrail?"

Tags: word-choice

I might be mistaken, but I feel odd calling the following "wooden handrails", since *handrails* are supposed to be made of metal.

[image]

[image: http://otherplacesotherlives.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/dsc_1790.jpg?w=425&h=640]

Is it OK to call it "handrail", "guard rail", or a "wooden handrail"?
Or is there a better term for it?

Comment: The whole construction above the deck is referred to as a balustrade.

Comment: Why do you assume that handrails are supposed to be made of metal?

Comment: @TheMathemagician OK, so I was wrong. So, the one in the first picture can be just called a handrail?

Comment: Handrails could be made of anything ([fiberglass or plastic](http://www.sdplastics.com/strongwellwaterparkapplications.html), [metal](http://www.tipsbytom.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/dsc013585.jpg) or [wrought-iron](http://www.hardyfence.com/images/wrought-iron/handrails/executive-handrail.jpg), wood or [pipe](http://cdn.simplifiedbuilding.com/images/projects/cable-rail-pipe-handrail_800.jpg)). There's nothing redundant about _wooden handrail_, just like there would be nothing redundant about _red car_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the defininiton of handrails from a few sources:

> [OxfordOnline](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/handrail?q=handrail) : 
>  a rail fixed to posts or a wall for people to
>   hold on to for support.
>
> [Reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/handrail?s=t):
>  a rail serving as a support or guard at the side of
>   a stairway, platform, etc.
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handrail):
>   a narrow [rail](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rail) for grasping with the hand as a support.

So, it be wrong to assume that rails are metallic. I agree the word rings in the metallic character as we (at least I do) quickly think of the rail-roads. :)
And as @Edwin Ashworth tells us, we can use *balustrade* for rails supported by pillars or columns. Here is a good definition about it:

> [balustrade](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/balustrade?q=balustrade): 
>  a railing supported by [balusters](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/baluster?q=balusters),
>   especially one forming an ornamental parapet to a balcony, bridge, or
>   terrace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I'm not a native-English speaker. Is *balustrade* a commonly used by people? I think of all the novels I've read, I'd never came across with the term.

Comment: _Balustrade_ may be a more technically precise term, but the word [_handrail_](http://www.google.com/search?q=deck+handrail&hl=en&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=o-1eUZSIMbOj4AOSxIHoDw&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1018&bih=731) could be used as well.

Comment: @janoChen you are welcome. and I feel a good learner never hesitate s to ask questions. :) btw. please accept it as an answer if you are satisfied with the answer, so we can think of this question as resolved (and I get more Points! muhhahahhahahah )

Comment: More people would probably opt for _parapet_ than _balustrade_, at least for the bridge.

Comment: but its not really a wall right?

Comment: *Parapet*? I think of parapets as living on roofs or balconies, not bridges.

Comment: @Peter They often do - but they're happy on bridges too. Check at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parapet ; I was just agreeing that _balustrade_, though probably the most accurate term here, is not too commonly used.

Comment: We'd never call _those_ walls. Perhaps some people would ball brick or stone parapets walls, though.

Comment: I think I'd just call them *railings*, although I have now learned that bridges can indeed have parapets.

Comment: @PeterShor  Railings surely refer to the uprights and not the horizontal bar that goes across the top? I would call that a rail or handrail, no matter what it was made of.

Comment: @Mynamite: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/railing): "*railing*: a barrier consisting of a rail and supports". So the *rail* or *handrail* is the part on top, the *balusters* are the uprights supporting it, and *railing,* *parapet,* and *balustrade* are words for the entire thing.

Comment: @PeterShor  You're quite right of course, but I think it's that old US/UK thing. I don't know anyone who would call the uprights 'balusters' except perhaps a carpenter. The thing that springs to my mind is Alan Garner's 'Elidor' from 1965 -  ["two wooden laths nailed together for the sword, a rusty iron railing for the spear, a cracked cup for the goblet, and a dull lump of stone"](http://www.murrayewing.co.uk/mewsings/2012/08/05/elidor-by-alan-garner/). The iron railing is the pointed type often seen around public parks over here (admittedly no handrail).

Comment: @Mynamite: I think only carpenters would call uprights *balusters* in the U.S., too. But there is a US/UK difference: [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/railing?q=railing) say that as a synonym for *balustrade*, the word *railings* is usually plural in the U.K., so using *railing* for a single support is natural through backformation. I think in the U.S., we'd call one a *support, post, upright,* but not a *railing*.

Answer (score 1):

Stair guide rails on houses are good examples of wooden handrails. Anyways, I would just like to add that you can say 'wooden handrail' if you feel that it would add to your explanation or add to the sort of visual or tactile imagery that you are trying to project. Balustrade would be acceptable too but only if you don't mind your audience not knowing what they are initially.