# More precise term for wide handrail

Tags: synonyms

Is there a better term than "wide [handrail](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110517/should-i-refer-to-the-following-as-a-handrail-guard-rail-or-a-wooden-hand)" for stone (or similar material) balustrades wide enough that a person can lie on? I'm looking for a word that when put into Google Image search, would produce something like this:

[image]

I've tried "railing", "rail", "balustrade", "parapet", but they all produce narrow railings.

Comment: The man is _lying_ on the balustrade, not _laying_ on it! I don't think there is any specific word; you could try _broad_ as well as _wide_.

Comment: I tried both "stone balustrade" and "stone parapet" and got reasonable image results.

Comment: I tried the words suggested in Google Images, and came to the conclusion that Google Images doesn't properly understand either *balustrade* or *parapet*.  And I certainly wouldn't call anything I could lie comfortably on a *rail*, most certainly not a *handrail* which carries the connotation that I can (perhaps comfortably) get a grip on it with my hand.

Comment: Corcovado on a clear day.

Answer (score 2):

Although a Google search doesn't show many image results, **parapet** is the right word for the place where the guy is lying.

> [**parapet**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parapet) -   [ˈper-ə-pət  , -ˌpet, ˈpa-rə-]  A low wall along the edge of something high such as a bridge or roof, a low wall or railing along the edge of a balcony, roof, etc.

[image]

> **Etymology** - 1580s, from Middle French parapet "breastwork" (16c.), or directly from Italian parapetto, from para- "defense" (see para- (2)) + petto "breast," from Latin pectus (see pectoral (adj.))

The above [picture](https://www.schock-na.com/en-us/parapet-rooftop-products) shows how the Italian word "parapetto", which means "supports the chest", fits perfectly what the structure is supposed to be used for.